# W123 200e stromberg engine shuts off and i have to wait at least an hour to turn on the car

Tags: mercedes-benz, stall

I have a w123 200e with a stromberg carburetor, auto gear, petrol
Whenever i start the car, as the engine gets warmer, the car shuts off, and i need to wait like around 30 mins to an hour for it to be able to start, and after a few minutes, it happens again,

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are getting heat soak in the carburettor - basically it is getting too hot and the fuel is vapourising before it can be added to the air mixture, and so not enough fuel is getting to the engine.

I'm not familiar with the layout of that engine - is it a crossflow (inlet and exhaust on opposite sides) or are they both on the same side? If the latter, is there a heatshield between the carb and the exhaust manifold? A common cause of this issue is that heatshield falling off...